# How do I send cPanel error logs by email

Tags: cpanel, error-logging

I've never looked at the error logs generated by cPanel, but figure it would be a good idea. I am talking about the log you get when you log-in to cPanel, and click on "Error Log".

The first thing to do is to make sure I'm regularly checking them, and the best way I can think of is to receive them by email. However I cannot see how to do that, and googling `cpanel receive "error log" by email` doesn't turn anything up.

I suspect that this error log might be an Apache error log, in which case having it sent by email might not be possible (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246143)).

Notes: This is a shared server, but I do have ssh access.

Comment: Your best option is probably to write a PHP script that reads the content of your error log (You can define the location in your php.ini) and emails it to you. Then you can add a cron job to automatically execute the script for you.

Comment: Thanks for that idea, which I hadn't thought of. I will investigate it and report back if I manage to make it happen!